Using Ionic/Vue with AWS Amplify Gen 2. How to make Google and Apple Sign in work on native iOS app?
I've got an app I'm building with Ionic and Vue 3 to run both on the web and natively.
My backend is handled by AWS Amplify Gen 2. The "Gen 2" part is important!
I have Google Sign In and Sign In With Apple working for the web, but from my iOS both leave the app, open a sign in page in Mobile Safari, and then redirect to another web page. When I go back to the native app, it seems locked and when I relaunch shows a blank screen.
Any ideas? Am I totally misusing the technology, trying to mix Amplify Gen 2, a native app, and Ionic/Vue?
Thanks!
